# Ansible test hosts fails

Tags: ansible

Just starting out with Ansible. I configured the hosts file like this:

```
[webserver]
<remote-server-ip> ansible_user=<user> ansible_private_key_file=<full-path-to-private-ssh-key>
```

When I run:

```
ansible all -m ping
```

I get:

```
<remote-server-ip> | UNREACHABLE! => {
"changed": false,
"msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer\r\n",
"unreachable": true
```

I can connect with no issues if I run:

```
ssh -i <full-path-to-private-ssh-key> <user>@<remote-server-ip>
```

Notes:

1. There is no password on the SSH key.
2. The project is located at `~/my_project_name`.
3. I also tried using `ansible_connection=local`, and while `ansible all -m ping` appeared to work, in reality all it does is allow me to execute tasks that modify the host machine Ansible is running on.
4. The ansible.cfg file has not been modified, though it is in a different directory: `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`.

Comment: what happens when you run `ansible webserver -m ping`?

Comment: @harshavmb - the result is the same

Comment: Can you run `ansible all -m ping -vv` ? It gives more verbose logs

Comment: @harshavmb - I added log to the notes.

Comment: Format the debug log. AFAIK, ansible needs python to run commands/playbooks on target system. Is python present on your target? Finally, can you make this change to your hosts file `<remote-server-ip> ansible_connection=local ansible_user=<user> ansible_private_key_file=<full-path-to-private-ssh-key>` . Also the ansible user has `sudo` access on remote machine? There could be other reasons though am not sure.

Comment: @harshavmb `ansible_connection=local` worked! If you post it as answer I'll give you a vote. -- thanks

Comment: Glad to see the issue is resolved!

Answer (score 1):

Ansible by default tries to connect to localhost through ssh. For localhost, set the `ansible_connection` to local in your hosts file shown below.

`<remote-server-ip> ansible_connection=local ansible_user=<user> ansible_private_key_file=<full-path-to-private-ssh-key>`

Refer [this](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html) documentation for more details.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `ansible_connection=local` doesn't actually appear to work. According to the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters),  this will just setup a non-SSH connection to the host machine - this doesn't seem that useful as I am using Ansible to setup remote machines over SSH. Any ideas?

Comment: If `ansible_connection=local` worked for 2.2.0.0 version and didn't work for 2.3.1 then you need to raise a different question as they are not same. You confirmed adding above parameter worked for you. Not sure, why it didn't work now.

Comment: Actually `ansible_connection=local` passes tests for both versions. The problem is that the hosts file should not be configured to use 'local'. Tasks will get executed to the local machine instead of the remote when you run the playbook. This caused me a bit of confusion as the test was passing, but nothing was getting updated on the remote server. Thanks for the advice anyway though.

Comment: Okay, Can you post `ansible.cfg` file you are using? What is the task you are trying to do on remote servers? Your question just says about ping module.

Comment: Do you have access to copy files onto remote servers? Have you checked the directory permissions? Your latest update and the initial post doesn't match at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146984/discussion-between-christopher-carlson-and-harshavmb).

Answer (score 0):

I think I saw this earlier, can you try adding below in the hosts file and see if that works

```
      ansible_connection=ssh ansible_port=22
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that this is an issue with the version of Ansible I was using (2.3.1). Using version 2.2.0.0 works with no problems.